# What perl data structure is this?

Tags: perl, data-structures

```
my $struct = { 1 => "Image", 2 => "Audio", 3 => "Video" };
```

What data structure in perl does above statement represent ? is it a Hash or array ?

Thanks !

Comment: Looks like a homework question

Comment: @woolstar, A syntax error?

Comment: Ok, so I can't type.  Try 2: my $struct = { i => "Image" } ;

Answer (score 2):

`$struct` is hash reference (or hashref) - scalar variable that is pointing to hash (similar to C pointer, but not quite it).

To create hash, use:

```
my %hash = ( key1 => "value1", ... );
```

To create hashref, use braces:

```
my $hashref = { key1 => "value1", ... };
```

In this example, you can also create hashref using backslash operator`\` (similar to `&` operator in C):

```
my $hashref = \%hash;
```